# Cannot use 'sudo systemctl restart apache2' after `sudo apt-get install apache2` (Xenial Ubuntu running on WSL)

Tags: apache2, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**Formerly titled 'Cannot find httpd after sudo apt-get install apache2 (emulation of Ubuntu running on Windows)'**

So I installed [Canonical Group Limited Ubuntu App for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/store/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?rtc=1) after installing [Windows Subsytem For Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-win10) for an emulation of Ubuntu running on Windows 10.

Running `lsb_release -a`

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

So I ran `sudo apt-get install apache2` and I can see some evidence of install in that there now exists `/etc/apache2` directory and there is a default Apache index.html page at `/var/www/html/index/html`.

But there is no `httpd` in `usr/bin` or `usr/sbin`.

So where is httpd ?

I cannot start Apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2` it reports

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the Apache packages don't install an `httpd` binary. Run this command to find all the binaries installed by the apache packages: `dpkg-query -L apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils | grep -E '/usr/s?bin/'`

Comment: sudo systemctl restart apache2.service Works on Ubuntu 16.04 higher as long as systemd is running. reference https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-start-restart-stop-apache-web-server/

Comment: @Lazytux OP is running Ubuntu with WSL ([Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)) which doesn't seem to support `systemd` yet.

Answer (score 8):

Th systemctl  issue is covered (but not eaxctly solved) here
[systemctl doesn't work in Xenial · Issue #1579 · Microsoft_WSL · GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1579)

Instead of systemctl to start Apache use the following

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Comment: @Panther: I'll try, in the future.  I studied Linux a dozen years ago, so I'm rusty.  I'll try to remember to expand this answer once I figure out correct answer.